# Remix IDE error: send transaction failed : invalid address. if you use injected provider, please check it is properly unlocked

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I've got the error message in the title when I'm trying to deploy my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract University {
    address public owner;
    address public student;
    address firstName;
    address lastName;
    bytes32 Studies;
    uint age;
    uint DateOfBirth;
    bytes32 public caCertificate;
    bytes32 ipfs_hash;
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner()  {
        if (msg.sender == owner) _;
    }
    modifier onlyOwnerOrStudent() {
        if (msg.sender == owner || msg.sender == student) _;
    }
    function setstudent () public;

function getStudent () public;

event student(
    bytes32 firstNameName,
    bytes32 lastName,
    bytes32 Studies,
    uint age,
    uint DateOfBirth,
    bytes32 ipfs_hash
    );

function checkStudentExists() public constant returns (bool) {
    if (student == firstName && student == lastName) return true;
}

function setIPFSHash(bytes32 _ipfs_hash) public onlyOwnerOrStudent {
    ipfs_hash = _ipfs_hash;
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Which environment are you using? ('Run' tab, 'Environment' box.)

Comment: Hi, I am using Injected Web3 environment....

Answer (score 1):

I'm only new to Ethereum and I got a similar error when trying to deploy a contract.

The problem was I wasn't logged into Metamask so couldn't approve the transaction. Are you using Metamask?

Answer (score 1):

Before running your code in remix ide, ensure that you logged into metamask. Then this error will not come.

Answer (score 0):

Metamask no longer exposes accounts by default. If you don't see the account listed in remix and you are sure you logged in to metamask but it still doesn't work, open the console on remix website and type:

```
window.ethereum.enable()
```

The above line of code should open a metamask prompt asking to allow connecting to the site. Click connect and you should see the account listed in the accounts dropdown in remix.